# Reselecting image from iPad

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a picker that allows the user to select an image from their iPad.  I want store some unique identifier of the image they select(such as the [image description] or something else?  Then I want to save that to a text file(Which I know how to do), then fetch that image from the phone at a later time to display.  What would be the best format to save this image to text so that I can get it later?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

filename, as after the release ALAssetsLibrary everything else is destroyed.